# Source code for android-16 doesn't match jar file

Tags: android

My Eclipse Android application is built with android.jar in android-sdk\platforms\android-16, and at a breakpoint I want to look at the following code in the call stack:

```
ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1522
```

I have the sources for android-16 in android-sdk\sources\android-16. However, there is no ViewRoot.java - the closest I have is ViewRootImpl.java in android-sdk\sources\android-16\android\view. The draw(boolean) function is there, but from line 2050 onwards. Line 1522 is in a totally different function.

So my question is: Why the mismatch in file names and line numbers?

My manifest has targetSdkVersion="15", but that shouldn't make any difference, surely? I have done a search for ViewRoot.java in the sources folder, but that only finds ViewRootImpl.java and ViewRootImpl_Delegate.java (whatever that is).

EDIT:
Added complete call stack

```
Spine [Android Application] 
DalvikVM[localhost:8613]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 670 in ChartView)) 
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ChartView.onDraw(Canvas) line: 670  
        ChartView(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6880 
        NineFrameLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1646 
        NineFrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373  
        LinearLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644    
        LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373 
        FrameLayout(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644 
        FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373  
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).drawChild(Canvas, View, long) line: 1644   
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).dispatchDraw(Canvas) line: 1373    
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).draw(Canvas) line: 6883 
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(FrameLayout).draw(Canvas) line: 357   
        PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(Canvas) line: 1862   
        ViewRoot.draw(boolean) line: 1522   
        ViewRoot.performTraversals() line: 1258 
        ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1859  
        ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 123 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3683    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<8> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<7> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
    Thread [<10> Binder Thread #3] (Running)    
    Thread [<11> Binder Thread #4] (Running)
```

It's what's going on in ViewRoot.draw that I'm interested in, because that's the point in the call stack (using step return in the debugger) where the view screen gets blanked out on a phone running Gingerbread (in my case an AVD - I don't possess that hardware). It's since I upgraded the UI to use SherlockActionBar, but the code in question is imported from Android - not the Sherlock library. But my question remains - why can't I find ViewRoot.java in the android-16 source, only a similar module with line numbers that don't tie in?

Comment: Please consider posting the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm assuming you mean the call stack. There is no stack trace, which I associate with a crash, or maybe that's just semantics. I will post it shortly (once I've run it up) if it helps to answer my question.

Comment: From what i understand the code lines you are getting will be relative to the android version the apk is running not the version it was compiled too. Especially if you consider that the android.jar it uses to compile only have method stubs, try to look at the version of the device of emulator you are running and see if the code matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line numbers and classes you see in your stack trace are relative to the version of android your apk is running on. In your case **Gingerbread**, so you need to look for the sources in that version of the sdk.
In your case the appropriate source code should be [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/view/ViewRoot.java#ViewRoot.draw%28boolean%29) assuming that is the sdk version your are using. If it isnt just change the version on that site and you should have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for that! When you think about it, it's obvious what the explanation is :-)